# Missing constraint for connecting view.top with dynamic height uilabel bottom

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I am trying to arrange 3 views - 1. Image view with fixed height and width 2. Textview with fixed width but dynamic height and 3. Tableview with fixed width and height adjusted according to available space after textview.

[image: Storyboard with highlighted view]

What constraints I am missing here. Why I need to give Textview or Tableviews Y pos or height constraint. Doesn't it make their height fixed?

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a height constant to your textview. Because autolayout can't figure out how many pixels to give to your both view.
If you want to adapt your height depending on the text, you can use :

```
TextViewHeightConstraint.constant = [TextView intrinsicContentSize].height
```

into your code after your link your constraint via iboutlet.

Comment: I know from the code it can be done. Even if I do not do any thing in code, with current constraint setup I am getting the expected behavior. It works perfectly. What I am trying to understand is why the compiler "complains" here? Is there any way to remove this error from Storyboard?

Comment: it complains because compiler can't know wich height it has to give to your textView AND to your tableView. You need to give to it at least one of this constraint. If you want to avoid this, you can use an UILabel, the intrinsic content size of uilabel will do the job.

Comment: Part 2 of this website -> https://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/